# when i re open my React project i encountering an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The specific error message I'm receiving is,

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

I'm uncertain about the cause and would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights to resolve this issue.
i don't understand why it occurs and how to fix it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

delete **node_moduled** folder and run npm i command, hope it will work.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work.